# What's the casting ability modifier of a scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting

Based on the table in the description of the [*spell scroll*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll) magic item:

A scroll of *charm person* has a spell DC of 13.

A scroll of *chromatic orb's* attack roll should be d20+5.

But what is the amount healed by a scroll of *cure wounds*?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Technically, it's undefined.

Which is dumb, and you should use either the spellcasting ability modifier of whichever class you have that has *Cure Wounds* on its spell list, or another number that I'll explain later.

First, the rules for magic items that cast spells (page 141 of the DMG), as pertaining to spellcasting ability:

> A magic item, such as certain staffs, may require you to use your own spellcasting ability when you cast a spell from the item.

So magic items "may require" you to use your own spellcasting ability. Next, the rules for spell scrolls (page 200 of the DMG):

> The level of the spell on the scroll determines the spell's saving throw DC and attack bonus, as well as the scroll's rarity, as shown in the Spell Scroll table.

Spell scrolls don't say anything about what you should use for spellcasting ability. They do say this:

> If the spell is on your class's spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully.

To use a spell scroll, you must have a spellcasting class that includes the spell on the scroll in its spell list. This, combined with the mention of your spellcasting ability above, strongly suggests that you should use your own.

However, there is another point to consider: the Spell Scroll table. The numbers it gives for attack modifier and saving throw DC line up exactly with those of a spellcaster who starts at level 1 with the ability score they use for spellcasting at 16, and increases it as they level to 20. Like so:

| Spell Level | Character Level | Proficiency Bonus | Ability Score | Ability Modifier | Save DC | Attack Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 16 | 3 | 8 + 2 + 3 = 13 | 2 + 3 = 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 16 | 3 | 8 + 2 + 3 = 13 | 2 + 3 = 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 4 | 8 + 3 + 4 = 15 | 3 + 4 = 7 |
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 18 | 4 | 8 + 3 + 4 = 15 | 3 + 4 = 7 |
| 5 | 9 | 4 | 20 | 5 | 8 + 4 + 5 = 17 | 4 + 5 = 9 |
| 6 | 11 | 4 | 20 | 5 | 8 + 4 + 5 = 17 | 4 + 5 = 9 |
| 7 | 13 | 5 | 20 | 5 | 8 + 5 + 5 = 18 | 5 + 5 = 10 |
| 8 | 15 | 5 | 20 | 5 | 8 + 5 + 5 = 18 | 5 + 5 = 10 |
| 9 | 17 | 6 | 20 | 5 | 8 + 6 + 5 = 19 | 6 + 5 = 11 |

So by that logic, a *Cure Wounds* spell should heal 1d8 + 3. It's up to you and your DM to decide whether you should use your own spellcasting ability or this "normal" spellcasting ability when you cast a spell using a spell scroll. Or, of course, some completely different number you come up with yourself. Personally, I think it makes the most sense to use your own.

Comment: I think there is also a rule/ruling that if you aren't a spellcaster, then your modifier is +0, in which case you would definitely want to use the modifier from the table.

Comment: @NickBrown Yeah, but you can't use spell scrolls unless you're a spellcaster, so the situation would never arise. Even the Thief's Use Magic Device ability doesn't let them use spell scrolls.

Comment: Oh, jeez.  There is not an explicit spellcaster requirement at the beginning of the Spell Scroll description, but it does look like the spell has to be on your class's spell list to even use it (so obviously non-casters cannot use these scrolls - they are unintelligible).  I skimmed the description and thought there was just a high DC to use another class's spell.

Comment: @Miniman ["Use Magic Device is intended to work with spell scrolls."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/784088247773175808)

Comment: For me, this is the key: "To use a spell scroll, you must have a spellcasting class that includes the spell on the scroll in its spell list. This, combined with the mention of your spellcasting ability above, strongly suggests that you should use your own."

Comment: @Doval Right! this was also mentioned in Sage Advice Compendium: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA255

Answer (score -4):

By all accounts, it should be the spellcasting modifier of the creature who wrote the scroll as they are the ones who poured their own spell power into it.  I believe that the chart above is on track for the math to calculate for the generic spell scroll; however, if you as the PC wrote your own or if it were written by a specific NPC that the DM has specified stats for, those stats should be used instead.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect because of the quote that the other answered has shown us. 'The level of the spell on the scroll determines the spell's saving throw DC and attack bonus, as well as the scroll's rarity, as shown in the Spell Scroll table.'. The original creatures spellcasting modifier has nothing to do with the spell scroll table.